# Styles not loading in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I have a site that needs some custom styles in Django and I can't get the static file to load.

I have a static folder inside my main folder - The one where manage.py lives, Inside there is a CSS folder that contains a style.css.

At the top of base.html, I load

```
{% load static %}
```

Then in the head of my HTML I load

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
```

and in my settings.py file I have loaded in

```py
# Static file route
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
```

When I load I just get a blank CSS file and no styles load, I'm fairly new to Django so please be kind, and thanks in advance.

Also, I want make sure my static folder is created in the right place:

[image: folder structure]

Comment: What's your base_dir ? Also check if `"django.contrib.staticfiles",` exist in your installed apps ?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
```

where `BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent`

check also that you have

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

From your screen your static is `css/style.css` but you load `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">` instead.
You need to load `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">`

Comment: So I have updated to give some more info

Answer (score 0):

You have to run in terminal:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

After every change of static files if I remember correctly.

Other then that, pressing F12 in a browser can show why a specific file isn't loading. So can the terminal/console where Django is running(or log files if no access to it).

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is crazy
but try to write your static css file(link rel="stylesheet") in the last line of your html head that worked very well for me after I tried all posted soultions